# ios custom UITableviewCell selected background color without SelectedBackgroundView

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xamarin.ios

Can anyone help me to set selected Background color of custom UITableviewCell without assigning selected background view property of cell.
Thank you.

Comment: I got a solution with setting only background color on cell selected. Thanks all for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

You can add view as a parent view of other cell components and change its colour.

Comment: hi Abd... thanks for your quick reply. But I didn't understood your logic. Can you please update me with sample small code if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I can express the hierarchy of the cell : 1- add background view (this view that you will change its colour on selection) , 2- add the other components that you want to add inside the first view.

Comment: Thanks @Abd for your response. I was having problem of selected color with background view on scrolling UITableview. I got a solution with setting only background color on cell selected.

Comment: @AbdAdoubi: Don't leave important information in comments; they're meant to be temporary. [Edit] your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit different approach, If you don't want to use `background-color` `property` or `selected background view property`. Then try to do as follow-

1. Add two images i.e. selected/unselected in your project.
2. Add `UIImageView` as `subView` of `custom UITableViewCell` below all `subViews` of `cell`.Then set `UIImageView` image and highlighted image with selected/unselected image.

try to run project and select your cell,then imageView image will change automatically to highlighted.

Hope this will solve your problem..